# Definition of dirac delta function why is it $1 / \epsilon$ and not some constant / epsilon?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

The definition that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(t) = 1$$
is based off of: $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} 1/\epsilon * \epsilon$$

So the limit of the value would approach one, but what if you change the function to $2/\epsilon$ or any other arbitrary constant.

In that case, the dirac delta function would become: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(t) = c$$

Which would lead to different answers when solving differential equations that include the delta function.

It's different, but wouldn't it still be a correct model for the derivative of the step function?

Comment: What do you mean with a proof of a function?

Comment: Well the proof that the integral from negative infinity to infinity of the delta function equals to 1

Comment: The $\delta$ function is not, technically, a function, so you can't prove that it's integral is anything. It is, intuitively, sort of a function, but it is actually something called a functional. It acts like a function in some ways, but it is not, in fact, a function.

Comment: I suppose Im asking why you can define the total area of this function as 1, and not some other constant.

Comment: @Goldname If it was some other constant you just change divide by the constant to get 1 and call your new function the delta function.

Comment: What do you mean divide by the other constant? What other constant

Comment: @Goldname They just mean if $\int f \,dx = c$, then letting $g := \frac{1}{c} f$ gives $\int g \,dx = \int \frac{1}{c} f \,dx = \frac{1}{c} \int f \,dx = \frac{1}{c} c = 1$.

Comment: In this case, f would be the delta function and g would be the delta function multiplied by a constant right? But I am not trying to get the area of the delta function multiplied by a constant. I just want the area of the delta function.

Comment: You don't 'prove' the delta function. It is defined as having integral one. Also a far better derivation of it is as the limit of a Gaussian distribution as the variance tends to $0$. If you replace $1$ by $k$ you just get a multiple of the delta function with integral $k$.

Comment: Isn't the delta function defined to be the derivative of the step function? In this case, how is the delta function also defined to have an integral of one, when you can show that it has a different value.

Comment: A common **rigorous definition** of the Dirac delta is $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x) f(x)dx \overset{def}= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1_{|x| < \epsilon}}{2|\epsilon|}  f(x)dx = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{1}{2\epsilon} \int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon f(x)dx = f(0)$$ **if $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$.**

Comment: If you go that way, $δ=H'$, then purely formally, $\int_{-a}^aδ(x)dx=H(a)-H(-a)=1-0=1$ which stays constant for $a\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

The Dirac delta is, in its strictest definition, a linear function on the space of continuous functions defined as
$$
\langle δ,f\rangle=f(0).
$$
Formally, but not with any integration theory behind it, this is also written as
$$
\int δ(x)·f(x)\,dx = f(0)
$$
Inserting the constant function $f(x)=1$ leads to
$$
\int δ(x)\, dx = 1
$$
Again, this is not an integral, this is the evaluation of the constant $1$ at $x=0$ written as if it were an integral.

There exist several approximation of the Dirac delta of the form $\phi_ϵ(x)=\frac1ϵ\phi(\frac xϵ)$ where $\phi$ is non-negative, integrable over $\Bbb R$ with integral value $1$. For these the integral
$$
\int_{\Bbb R}\phi_ϵ(x)·f(x)\,dx=\int_{\Bbb R}\phi(u)·f(ϵu)\,du
$$
is sensible as Riemann or Lebesgue integral, if the function classes of $f$ and $\phi$ match ($f$ continuous and $\phi$ with compact support or $f$ tempered and $\phi$ fast falling or ...)

With the given assumptions on $\phi$ one then gets
$$
\lim_{ϵ\to0}\int_{\Bbb R}\phi_ϵ(x)·f(x)\,dx=f(0),
$$
but in this the limes and the integral can **not** be exchanged in any analytical sense, it is only formally or symbolically that the limes is written as if one could exchange them.